# Changing georeferenced .tif file with GDAL SetGeoTransform?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to change the pixel width and pixel height in the GeoTransform inside a georeferenced .tif file.  I wrote a bit of code to read the file then change the GeoTransform parameters and write another file. I cannot get the process to just change the file in question (and not make a new file).  Is there a way to just modify the file?  I have hundreds to modify so I do not want to do one at a time.  The following code works fine but it is a bit overkill.

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
try:
    from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
except:
    sys.exit('ERROR: cannot find GDAL/OGR modules')
# Enable GDAL/OGR exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()
OUTPUTPATH = r"G:\Myfiles\Imagery\Small\resize"
INPUTPATH = r"G:\Myfiles\Imagery\Small"


def readFile(filename):
    filehandle = gdal.Open(filename)
    redband = (filehandle.GetRasterBand(1)).ReadAsArray()
    greenband = (filehandle.GetRasterBand(2)).ReadAsArray()
    blueband  = (filehandle.GetRasterBand(3)).ReadAsArray()
    geotransform = filehandle.GetGeoTransform()
    print(geotransform)
    print(f"Total raster bands {filehandle.RasterCount}")
    #(12709752.0, 0.25, 0.0, 562848.0, 0.0, -0.25)
    offX, xsize, line1, offY, line2, ysize = geotransform
    geotransform = (offX, 1.0, line1, offY, line2, -1.0)
    geoproj = filehandle.GetProjection()
    
    xsize = filehandle.RasterXSize
    ysize = filehandle.RasterYSize    
    print(geotransform)
    print(geoproj)
    filehandle = None
    return xsize,ysize,geotransform,geoproj,redband,  greenband, blueband

def writeFile(filename,geotransform,geoprojection, redband,  greenband, blueband):
    (ny,nx) = redband.shape
    format = "GTiff"
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    driver.Register()
    #dst_ds = driver.Create(filename, x, y, 1, data.DataType)
    #dst_ds = driver.Create(filename,nx, ny,3,options=["INTERLEAVE=PIXEL"])
    dst_ds = driver.Create(filename, nx, ny, bands = 3, eType = gdal.GDT_Byte) #was gdal.GDT_int16
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)    # specify coords
                   # WGS84 lat/long
    dst_ds.SetProjection(geoprojection) # export coords to file
    reds = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    greens = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2)
    blues = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3)
    reds.WriteArray(redband)   # write r-band to the raster
    reds.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
    reds.FlushCache()
    greens.WriteArray(greenband)   # write g-band to the raster
    greens.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
    greens.FlushCache()
    blues.WriteArray(blueband)   # write b-band to the raster
    blues.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
    blues.FlushCache()
    
    #Close main raster dataset
    dst_ds.FlushCache()                     # write to disk
    dst_ds = None
    reds = None
    blues = None
    greens = None
   
    redband = None
    blueband = None
    greenband = None
   

path1 = INPUTPATH + r"\*.tif"
filelist = glob.glob(path1)

for oneFile in filelist:
    print(f"File = {oneFile} " )
    InputBaseName = os.path.split(oneFile)[1]
    [xsize, ysize, geotransform, geoproj, R,G,B] = readFile(os.path.join(INPUTPATH, oneFile))
    
    writefilename = os.path.join(OUTPUTPATH,InputBaseName)
    writeFile(writefilename, geotransform, geoproj, R,G,B)
    

print("Done")
```

If I didn't have to write a new file, this would be a bit quicker.
This **video** helped a bunch - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_BsFdV_LUk

Comment: Kadir, you are right.  I ended up not doing anything with it except launching it from inside QGIS.  I'll take that part out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the raster size (pixel width / height) of an existing GeoTIFF file. You must write a new file.